# How to call function when assigning an object a value

Tags: javascript

Hi I the following functions in separate js files

```
//in js file 1
setUsername: function(v){
document.Load.LogUsername = v;
}
//in js file 2{wrapper for js file 1}
LogUserName: function(v)
{
  return myobject.SetLoguserName(v);
}
```

When `document.Load.LogUsername = v;` is called i need it to call the LogUserName function. LogUserName is a wrapper for setUsername. Any ideas how to get this to work. I know if change 
`document.Load.LogUsername = v;` to `document.Load.LogUsername(v);` then it works but i was asked not to change the js file 1

Comment: please edit your question, so we can read your javascript code properly

Comment: I don't think there's a cross-browser way to do this, or even any way at all in IE, but I'm interested to see what the cogniscenti have to say.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the original function, like this:

```
var originalLogUserName = document.Load.LogUsername;
LogUserName: function(v)
{
    return originalLogUserName.call(myobject, v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but i was asked not to modify the original function

Comment: @wolv: This is not modifying the original function.  This code can run in the second script and simply saves the original function to a variable.  You can then call the function from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters).  E.g.:

```
document.Load = 
{
  set LogUsername(v) 
  {
    myobject.SetLoguserName(v);
  }
};
```

Comment: @SLaks, [this post](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/) says Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera all support this syntax.  I verified in Chrome.

Comment: While all those browsers implement this syntax, I'm pretty sure it will be deprecated soon, in favor of the ES5 `Object.defineProperty`, `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.create` methods, which all use plain objects as property descriptors (no new syntax introduced :).